# Dirac function in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am using a structural software that uses TCL as a programming language.

Does anyone how to define dirac functions in TCL? From the examples I got hold of, 4 arguments are required. What do they correspond to?
This is how the function is defined in my examples:

```
#
diract(tint,0*dt,dt,dt)
#
```

Thank you in advance

PS: I am struggling to find some good documentation. Any recommendation ?

Comment: The example you gave doesn't look like Tcl.   Tcl commands don't use arguments inside of parentheses except for math functions that are used with `expr` and conditionals:  http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm

Answer (score 0):

Given that we have a finite step size (because we're using IEEE double precision floating point, the [Dirac delta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) is just this:

```
proc tcl::mathfunc::delta {x} {
    expr {$x == 0.0 ? 4.49423283715579e+307 : 0.0}
}
```

That gives a delta function with a very large impulse at the origin (where the width of the impulse is determined by the size of the smallest non-denormalized number; that number is one of the largest that can be represented by floating point without using infinity).

That's not all that useful, as it's using floating point equality in its definition (and that rightfully has some *major* caveats attached to it). More usefully is fact that [the integral of it](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeavisideStepFunction.html) is such that it is 0 when *x* is less than 0 and 1 when *x* is more than 0.

I'm not sure what the arguments you're looking to provide mean, especially given that `0*dt` one of them.

Comment: The exact choice of what value to use at x=0 is tricky to say the least. Using the Heaviside function is so much easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.

I have now solved my problem.
The structural software I am using combines some functions defined in TCL with its own functions.